# What's the relation between the different clans?

Tags: plot-explanation, mad-max-fury-road

I am really confused about the relation between the different clans/families/groups in Mad Max Fury Road. This might simply result from the fact that I haven't seen any of the earlier Mad Max movies, but please help me out here.

The different groups all have distinctive outfits and vehicles and are lead by different bosses. For example the warboys seem to all be bald and wearing some kind of white color on their skins, one of the other groups we see seems to prefer motorcycles to cars etc.

At the start of the movie, when Furiosa abducts the truck, they get attacked by one of the rivaling clans, apparently because they entered their territory. The implication is that there is some kind of war going on between the groups.

When Furiosa reaches the mountains, she is followed by 2-3 different clans, from what I can tell, which are coming from all sides. However, when the rocks come down and they are cut off all at the same side, instead of fighting each other they join efforts.

**What did I miss, were they not at war with each other a few minutes earlier? What reason would they have to abandon their differences just to follow one truck?** (Especially since only the warboys know initially that the girls are in there.)

Or am I confusing different parties here?

Answer (score 12):

Now first of all, the previous movies wouldn't really clear that up either, they simply had completely different people and groups on their own, [not related to the story or characters of this movie at all](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34351/49).

The movie doesn't explicitly explain the whole political situation, but that post-apocalyptic world it depicts is split into **various smaller groups and clans which pretty much all fight for their own survival and interests**. It's just a big mad carnival of insanity. However, some of them still have some kind of alliances with each other while others might have wars and others simply don't give a damn (or don't even know of each other) and just judge each encounter on its own.

But you did indeed mix some things up here. **The War Boys led by Immortan Joe seemed to have some kind of alliance (be it merely trade-based or even deeper) with the guys from the Bullet Farm and from Gas Town**, which is apparent from the fact that Furiosa is supposed to drive that water/guzzoline/mother's milk tanker to those places and trade that stuff for other goods.

> **Immortan Joe:** Once again, we send off my War Rig to bring back guzzoline from Gas Town and bullets from the Bullet Farm!
>
> **War Boy:** We got vehicles from the Citadel. They're firing flares. They want reinforcements from Gas Town......and the Bullet Farm.

When she then leaves the road to Gas Town heading west, she leaves that groups' territory and enters the territory of some other clan (the "Buzzards" with their spiked cars), who are either pissed at being hurt in their "territorial rights" or simply want the stuff that's in the tanker. The War Boys even help her fight against them (since she still carries a valuable good, the mothers, even if she "stole" them). She later also meets other guys that only have their personal interests in mind, like the motorcycle gang living in the canyon (the "Rocky Riders") with whom she has a deal to seal off the canyon in exchange for the fuel but who then go after her when they feel betrayed.

> **Observer:** Your produce ain't going to Gas Town. She's gone off-road into hostile territory.
>
> **Furiosa:** I made a deal up ahead. Safe passage. I don't know if it's still any good.

But the people that assist Immortan Joe's War Boys and follow their convoy after joining him at the entrance of the canyon are only the people from **Gas Town** (led by this fat guy with the nose thingy) and the **Bullet Farm** (led by this shooting-mad guy who later loses his eyesight). **Only they help Immortan Joe in his cause because of their whatever-natured alliance**, but even they remark at various points that they don't really see the use of such an exhaustive and resource-draining chase for what simply are "family problems".

> **Rocky Rider:** You said: "A few vehicles in pursuit. Maybe." We count three War Parties!

Comment: Didn't Immortan and the other leaders call each other "brother" at some point? Was this just like calling each other "bro" or "mate"?

Answer (score 9):

There are four issues of comics that accompany Fury Road which tell the back Story of Max, Furiosa, Immortan Joe and Nux.

In the first issue with Nux and Immortan Joe's Story, it is explained that Immortan Joe was a former Militant leader. Colonel Joe Moore, a veteran of the Oil Wars and a Hero of the Water Wars.

In his party he had a henchman called Major Kalashnikov, and when they ventured into the Wasteland they spared the life of a fat man who he told them about an Aquifer where they could find water.

Out in the Wasteland, north of The Citadel they found an old Oil Refinery and to the west an abandoned Lead Mine.

The Fatman become the People Eater, Guardian of Gastown and Major Kalashnikov was appointed The Bullet Farmer of the lead mine were they produced ammunition.

So the Citadel, Gas Town and Bullet Farm were all part of the same triumvirate that ruled the Wasteland, with Immortan Joe looking like the strongest influence.

Answer (score -1):

Joe had the water so it made him the biggest and baddest. If he wants to waste resources for a family fight the other two have to agree. Bullets are important to whoever owns the water leads. Leaving gastown, fatman third in this army.

Comment: So if u want to rule in a wasteland control the water..Why not gas, power,or mines..Simple boardertown had power lights etc.but most getting to the tiwn was on foot.cars,trucks and su h orgreat but your body doesnt need them to stay alive..mines rhe same way..But water your body needs and with water I control food,making

Comment: Hi Dwayne, welcome. You can [edit your answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/64546/edit) to add this information.